# Unexpected results in Access SQL query with LIKE %x%

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two questions:

1. List the ShipmentID, ShipperName, and ShipperInvoiceNumber of all shippers whose name starts with 'AB'.

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ShipmentID, ShipperName, ShipperInvoiecNumber 
FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE ShipperName LIKE ‘AB%’;
```

It shows me wrong at the symbol of the percentage that is my mistake!!

2. Assume DepartureDate and ArrivalDate are in the format of MM/DD/YY. List the ShipmentID, ShipperName, ShipperInvoiceNumber, andd ArrivalDate of all shipments that departed in Decemeber?

my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ShipmentID, ShipperName, ShipperInvoiceNumber, ArrivalDate, 
DepartureDate
```

FROM SHIPMENT WHERE DepartureDate LIKE ‘%-12-%’;

Again the mistake it shows me at the percentages sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really just a typo, because you are using MacOS curly quotes in the `WHERE` clause instead of proper double quotes.  In addition, the Access `LIKE` pattern for starts with `AB` is `AB*`.  Taking both into account, use the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ShipmentID, ShipperName, ShipperInvoiecNumber 
FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE ShipperName LIKE "AB*";
```

For your second query, use the `MONTH()` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ShipmentID, ShipperName, ShipperInvoiceNumber, ArrivalDate, DepartureDate 
FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE MONTH(DepartureDate) = 12;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am using Microsoft OP.

Comment: Is the arrival date a text column or a date column?

Comment: Is a date column.

Comment: There's nothing Mac about curly quotes, they are available on every platform which supports Unicode. In the historical past, Mac software was somewhat more likely to change straight ASCII quotes into curly Unicode quotes everywhere, but Microsoft has never shunned from imitating and perfecting bad ideas.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed, but I have only actually had this problem with Mac editors, some of which render curly quotes when pressing the single quote key.

Comment: Some people don't have a real editor and use a word processor to write code. I have also seen this when people copy/pasted code from a blog which "helpfully" changed quoting to be more typographically pleasant, where of course correctness in code is much more important than appearance.